# Set slider automatically to a default start value

Tags: javascript, slider, default

I want to be able to create a default value for a slider. Underneath I have simplified my code as much as I figured possible. I want to be able to adapt the start position of the slider. In underneath example i'd like to see my slider start at 2007 in stead of the standard 2006. I got the slider from an example. Working with the $ sign is new to me. Anybody got an idea how to do this?

```
<script>
    var map;
    var wmsLayer;
    var URL;
    var legend;
    var index;
    require(["dojo/query", "esri/map", "esri/layers/WMSLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend", "esri/config", "dojo/domReady!"],
      function (query, Map, WMSLayer, Legend, esriConfig) {

          esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/proxy_gcx.php";

          map = new Map("map", {
              basemap: "topo",
              center: [5.5, 52.485],
              minZoom: 8,
              maxZoom: 13,
              zoom: 8,
              slider: true
          });

          map.on("load", function () {
              query("#lplist").on("change", function (e) {
                  var value = e.currentTarget.value;
                  switch (value) {
                      case "Option 1":
                          <SET SLIDER TO DEFAULT 2007>
                          break;
                      case "Option 2":
                          <SET SLIDER TO DEFAULT 2007>
                          break;
                  };
              });
          });
      });

    $(function slider() {
        var select = $("#Jaartal");
        var slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
            min: 1,
            max: 2,
            range: "min",
            value: select[0].selectedIndex + 2,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                index = ui.value - 1;
                select[0].selectedIndex = index;
                if (select[0][index].text === "2006") {
                }
                if (select[0][index].text === "2007") {
                }
            }
        });
        $("#Jaartal").change(function () {
            slider.slide("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="reservation">
    <div style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight:bold;">
        Lineair
    </div>
    <label for="Jaartal">Jaar</label>
    <select name="Jaartal" id="Jaartal">
        <option>2006</option>
        <option>2007</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="lppanel" class="roundedCorners">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <div style="font-size: 16pt; font-weight:bold;">
                    Gegeven
                </div>
                <div style="padding:10px;">
                    <select id="lplist">
                        <option value="choose" selected="selected">(Selecteer een optie)</option>
                        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It does. Thank you that is very helpful. But I'd actually like to do change it outside of the slider. In my total script I have a dropdown menu. Everytime someone uses it I want the slider to jump back to a certain position. To be able to do that I need to adapt the slider outside the slider function. But your previous comment might make me able to do that so thank you very much.

Comment: Use the same method in the .change event? `+2`

Comment: Whenever the dropdown menu is used the position of the slider does not adapt. I could include the .change event but it will not be activated if I just copy the two lines of the .change event.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create an example/demo please?

Comment: Its quite a long script. I tried to simplify it with the previous code but here it is with a lot of lines that are probably not important. I have added two lines in the code where I'd like my slider to be changed. This with the text: <SET SLIDER TO DEFAULT 2007>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are deriving the value based on the selectedIndex of a selection box.

The smartest solution would be to set the selection box default to the value you want like so:

```
    <select name="Jaartal" id="Jaartal">
        <option>2006</option>
        <option selected>2007</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: This is helpful! Whenever someone opens my page it automatically jumps to the slider position I want. I have a dropdown menu. I want this automatically to happen whenever someone changes the value of the dropdown menu. How would I do that?

Comment: `$("#idofdropdowncontrol").change(function () {
            slider.slide("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
        });`

This assumes that the index matches that of your "Jaartal" control.